# Saving webcam Snapshot silverlight to jpeg

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Ive a Question (im really new in silverlight).

Using "saveFileDlg.SafeFileName.ToString();" i can get the name of image file test.jpeg, but how i can get the full path "c:\images\test.jpeg" OR how i can put in the source code an static path as "c:\images\".

I aprecciate very much your help, coz im developing an access control applicattion and i wish capture images of our visitors in my job.

```
   if (saveFileDlg.ShowDialog().Value)
     {
         using (Stream dstStream = saveFileDlg.OpenFile())
         {
             SaveSnapshot(dstStream);
           "i can get file name but not full paht"  
              LblPath.Content = saveFileDlg.SafeFileName.ToString();

         }
     }
```

Exist the other way, to save a image file directly to static path like "c:/images/xxxx.jpg"

Thanks again. Augusto M. Quito - Ecuador Southamerica

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons Silverlight deliberately limits the Open and Save dialogs to filename only in standard applications. In order for you application to get be able to access the full filename it would need to be installed as an out-of-browser app with elevated trust.